# How can I show the current year in Ubuntu's Clock-indicator/applet?

Tags: ubuntu, clock

For a long time, I've wanted to make Ubuntu 12.04's clock show the current year; I like it to show up in my screen-shots.

However, there is no gui configuration for doing this:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-panel/+bug/465689

Does anyone know how I might change this in some configuration file or something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With due respect to the [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43999/how-to-change-the-date-format/44025#44025) helping me figure out, let's customize the indicator-datetime.

```
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.datetime time-format "'custom'"
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.datetime custom-time-format "'%a, %d. %h  %H:%M %Y'"
```

That would give an output of "Mon, 02, Jul 21:00 2012".

You can customize the format as long as they are understood by `strftime`. For other formats, you can consult the [manpage for the `strftime` command [image: Manpage icon]](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/strftime) and customize accordingly.

Comment: gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.datetime time-format "'custom'" ; gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.datetime custom-time-format "'%A | %m-%d-%Y | %l:%M%p'"